# column index not improving select statement (Android)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, indexing

I have a database table with 2.5 million rows. I query this table by either one column (item_no) or two columns (item_no & subitem_no). In order to optimize my query I created two indexes. One for item_no and one for the pair of item_no and subitem_no.

**Example:**

```
CREATE INDEX Idx2 ON master(item_no);
CREATE INDEX Idx3 ON master(item_no, subitem_no);
```

Now when I run this query in SQLite browser:

```
SELECT component, hours, unit, price
FROM master
WHERE barcode = "234567"
AND item_no = "1234"
```

or this one:

```
SELECT component, hours, unit, price
FROM master
WHERE barcode = "234567"
AND item_no = "1234"
AND subitem_no = "34"
```

It executes extremely fast. Around 76ms - 186ms. This is what I want, the original select statement without the indexes took in between 4000 - 6000ms. So its the huge improvement I was looking for. So now I load the database onto my android device (Samsung Galaxy S6) and give it the same indexes. No improvement on query speed... at all, the select statement still takes 4000 - 6000ms to run.

Here's how I'm doing it. Please let me know if you see any errors or you can explain why I'm not seeing the expected performance increase.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX Idx2 ON master(item_no, subitem_no);");
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX Idx3 ON master(item_no);");

public ArrayList<Data> getData(String barcode, String itemNo) {
    ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Database db = Database.getInstance();
        db.open();  

        String where = BARCODE_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + ITEM_NO_COLUMN + " = ?";  
        String[] columns = {COMPONENT_COLUMN, HOURS_COLUMN, UNIT_COLUMN, PRICE_COLUMN};
        String[] args = {barcode, itemNo};
        String sort = COMPONENT_COLUMN + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = db.getDb().query(true, MASTER_TABLE, columns, where, args, null, null, sort, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setComponent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COMPONENT_COLUMN)));
            data.setHours(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HOURS_COLUMN)));
            data.setUnit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UNIT_COLUMN)));
            data.setPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRICE_COLUMN)));

            dataList.add(data);

            if (!cursor.isLast()) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: put an index on `barcode`, as well! You should index all your `WHERE` and `JOIN` fields.

Comment: by that logic i might as well add one to the pair barcode and item_no. Thanks I'll try it

Comment: `item_no` is already indexed... or isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely but I read that if you are doing multiple selects, you should pair them with their own index as well. Meaning since the query is barcode AND item_no they should have a "paired" index, as stated here https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Comment: Also @Rotwang thank you, I just created the barcode index as well as the pair with item_no and it went down to 1ms response time. Still only in the SQLite browser though. My app is still very slow

Comment: Yes, right for the composite indices. Strange that the actual app doesn't benefit from that. It could depend on the SQLite version, but... The Galaxy S6 is a fairly recent device. And very pumped as well. Weird. Maybe you could take advantage of transactions?

Comment: very, I fixed it. It must of been a data cache issue. See my answer in a second

Comment: Oh, well. That makes sense. Nice that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It must of been a data cache issue. I restarted the device, uninstalled my app, then updated my index's per @Rotwang 's comments. Now when I run my app I get my desired 3ms query times.

**Here were my fixes:**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX Idx2 ON master(barcode, item_no, subitem_no);");
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX Idx3 ON master(barcode, item_no);");
```